# Using ERDAS Imagine 2020 orthophotos

Tags: arcgis-desktop, erdas-imagine, orthophoto, agisoft-photoscan

I am dealing with how to figure it out how to export an orthomosaic from my Agisoft Metashape because when I did the merge chunks there. When you merge there, it doesn't provide what I need because of smear or doesn't overlap correctly. So I had to export orthomosaic from each chunk and had to use ERDAS Imagine to create mosaic with seamline need to overlap correctly.

I could not figure it out how to export it into orthophotos I need in ERDAS Imagine.

I currently have Agisoft Metashape 1,7,3, ArcGIS Desktop 10.7, ArcGIS Pro 2.8, ERDAS Imagine 2020

Are there any solutions to that for me to export orthophotos in ERDAS 2020?

Comment: What is the file format of the raw orthophotos? Are you trying to find out a way to stitch all the orthos and export them to a format usable in ERDAS?? Like you want a workflow to create a mosaic in ArcGIS Pro/or ArcMap and exporting to ERDAS?

Comment: No, In Agisoft Metashape , at the final orthomosaic you had a custom script that can write from orthomosaic to orthophoto shapefile.  Problem is that when you merge all the chunks into one chunk it can create issues. So, I had to export two chunks that had already orthomosaic and then Open them in ERDAS with these two in .tif files.  When I mosaic them , I was able to set it to create seamlines. So from there, How you do use create Orthophotos using in ERDAS ? I could not find any solution .